# JavaScript Empty Setter Method Error

Tags: javascript, methods, getter-setter, empty-class

Given this code:

```
let person = {
_name: 'Lu Xun',
_age: 137
}
```

Need to add new setter method to change the person's age. I'm trying to add an empty `age` setter method, but get an error message Unexpected identifier or "Must have at least one parameter", though it asks for an empty method, to begin with.

Comment: Please show us *how* you tried to add that setter method which you got the error for.

Answer (score 0):

```
let person = {
_name: 'Lu Xun',
_age: 137,
set age(ageIn){

}
};
```

I got stuck on this too. It's looking for you to name the new variable, which is not explained well in the question.